# Comparing performance of Oracle's HotSpot in Client and Server modes

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

*Note: I have a minimal understanding of how HotSpot works in the sense of **inlining** and **branch prediction** but I'm looking into how both of these work right now.*

I'm trying to learn more about how Oracle's HotSpot VM works in both Client and Server modes. I've just read through [this](https://javapapers.com/core-java/jvm-server-vs-client-mode/) article on the differences between the two but now I'd like to see these in action.

Specifically, I was hoping to create a program (or a few programs, if needed) that will allow me to see and analyze the differences between the two modes. I happened to stumble across [JitWatch](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch), which seems like a handy tool that will allow me to analyze the decisions made in both modes.

Unfortunately, what's got me stumped is the type of program I should be creating that'll generate significantly different results when run in both modes.

**How can I go about creating a program that will allow me to do my analysis?**

Comment: There seems to be an impedance mismatch here. Client/Server JVM are mostly a high-level assortment of different tuning options. If you want to analyze JIT behavior that's something considerably more low level and should be broken down to the component you want to analyze. You probably should learn more about hotspot internals before continuing.

Comment: That article is more than five years old. The first thing, you should become aware of, is that for 64 bit builds of Oracle’s HotSpot JVM, there is no client JVM. Second, the distinction between client and server JVM is supposed to get superseded by tiered compilation. Since Oracle doesn’t offer 32 bit builds for Java 9 or newer, you intrinsically get no recent client JVM by default. You could make your own build but still would be riding a dead horse.